# Primitive roots modulo primes congruent to n!

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

> for $N \ge 4$. Show for prime numbers,  $p \equiv 1$ mod $(N!)$ that none of the numbers $1,2,...,N$ are primitive roots modulo $p$

I can't figure out where to start with this question, all I can think to use is the Legendre symbol and Euler's Criterion but I haven't been able to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prime $p$ is of the form $8k+1$, so $2$ is a quadratic residue of $p$.

Next we show that every odd prime $\le N$ is also a quadratic residue of $p$. From this it will follow that any integer $w$ whose prime divisors are $2$ and/or primes $\le N$ is a quadratic residue of $p$, and therefore not a primitive root of $p$.

A Legendre symbol calculation does it. Let $q$ be an odd prime $\le N$. By Quadratic Reciprocity, the Legendre symbol $(q/p)$ is equal to $(p/q)$. But $p\equiv 1\pmod{q}$, and therefore $(p/q)=(1/q)=1$.

Comment: You are welcome.